# How to read a txt file with the correct encoding after using a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to read a txt file using a function to show colors in terminal but since i do this all the accented words in file get a mess.. How to show the txt file colored and with the correct encoding?

```py
COLORS = {\
"black":"\u001b[30;1m",
"bold":"\u001b[1m",
"reset":"\u001b[0m",
"red": "\u001b[31;1m",
"green":"\u001b[32m",
"yellow":"\u001b[33;1m",
"blue":"\u001b[34;1m",
"magenta":"\u001b[35m",
"cyan": "\u001b[36m",
"white":"\u001b[37m",
"brown":"\u001b[94m",
"yellow-background":"\u001b[43m",
"black-background":"\u001b[40m",
"cyan-background":"\u001b[46;1m",
}

def colorText(text):
    for color in COLORS:
        text = text.replace("[[" + color + "]]", COLORS[color])
    return text

def lertxt() :
    f = open("olamundo.txt", "r")
    arquivo = "".join(f.readlines())
    print(colorText(arquivo))
    f.close()
    return

lertxt()
```

content of the txt file is:

> "Olá mundo"

the return is:

> "olÃ¡ mundo"

Comment: `"".join(f.readlines())` is the same as `f.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lolip (:

Just import io and, then:

```
import io

COLORS = {\
"black":"\u001b[30;1m",
"bold":"\u001b[1m",
"reset":"\u001b[0m",
"red": "\u001b[31;1m",
"green":"\u001b[32m",
"yellow":"\u001b[33;1m",
"blue":"\u001b[34;1m",
"magenta":"\u001b[35m",
"cyan": "\u001b[36m",
"white":"\u001b[37m",
"brown":"\u001b[94m",
"yellow-background":"\u001b[43m",
"black-background":"\u001b[40m",
"cyan-background":"\u001b[46;1m",
}

def colorText(text):
    for color in COLORS:
        text = text.replace("[[" + color + "]]", COLORS[color])
    return text

def lertxt() :
    with io.open("olamundo.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        text = f.read()
    print(colorText(text))
    f.close()
    return

lertxt()
```

Comment: did not work... unfortunally i think that the wrong encod ocurs when the function colorText is called right after the **open**, here: ```print(colorText(arquivo))```

Comment: It does works. Already tested it. I'll edit my answer with the full code (:

Answer (score 1):

```
First of all you should use like this arquivo = " ".join(f.readlines())
otherwise there won't be spaces a the string gets messed up.

you should use encoding: 
open("olamundo.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')
```